# Archive a NSMutableArray

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, arrays, nsmutablearray, nskeyedarchiver

I need to archive a NSMutableArray which is being controlled by an ArrayController. I tried this:

```
[NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:array];
```

But I got this error:

> `*** -[NSKeyedArchiver dealloc]: warning: NSKeyedArchiver deallocated
>   without having had -finishEncoding
>   called on it.`

How may I solve that please?

Comment: What kind of objects does your array contain? Can you confirm that all objects implement the NSCoding protocol?

Answer (score 1):

The root object of the graph you're archiving and anything referenced/contained by it must conform to < [NSCoding](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Protocols/NSCoding_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html) > protocol. See [Encoding and Decoding Objects](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/Archiving/Tasks/codingobjects.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000948-BCIHBJDE) for code examples for making your classes compliant (don't forget to "adopt" the protocol in your objects' interface declaration: `@interface MyClass : NSObject < NSCoding >`).

Comment: That doesn't help us help you. :-) Post your code and describe how it's not working.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot. I got these error:

2010-02-28 22:22:18.145 My app[53732:a0f] -[content encodeWithCoder:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x100189740
2010-02-28 22:22:18.146 My app[53732:a0f] -[content encodeWithCoder:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x100189740

Comment: Might be a stupid question, but have you actually implemented the `encodeWithCoder:` method for the objects that are in the array?

Comment: All this back-and-forth questioning would be completely unnecessary if you'd post the relevant code.

Comment: I just noticed that it does not happen with any other array. The problem is the one being controlled by the array controller.